# Change row value dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have the following information in a DataFrame in Python:

```py
##    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   colum
##0  206  214  021  122  554     2
##1  226  234  123  456  789     4
##2  245  253  558  855  123     5
##3  265  272  000  111  222     4
##4  283  291  214  589  996     1
```

and I need to generate a new column depending on the value that contains the colum column, in the following way:

```py
##    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   colum   newColum
##0  206  214  021  122  554     2       214
##1  226  234  123  456  789     4       456
##2  245  253  558  855  123     5       123
##3  265  272  000  111  222     4       111
##4  283  291  214  589  996     1       283
```

I do not know if I am clear in my request, I thank who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) and mapping integers to your column labels:

```
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, 'x' + df['colum'].astype(str))

print(df)

    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5  colum  new
0  206  214   21  122  554      2  214
1  226  234  123  456  789      4  456
2  245  253  558  855  123      5  123
3  265  272    0  111  222      4  111
4  283  291  214  589  996      1  283
```

Comment: this solution is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy indexing`:

```
df['new'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df)),  df['colum'] - 1]
print (df)
    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5  colum  new
0  206  214   21  122  554      2  214
1  226  234  123  456  789      4  456
2  245  253  558  855  123      5  123
3  265  272    0  111  222      4  111
4  283  291  214  589  996      1  283
```